# FFmpeg av_read_frame not reading frames properly?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Alright, so I've downloaded some raw UHD sequences in .yuv format and encoded them with ffmpeg in .mp4 container (h264 4:4:4, 100% quality, 25fps). When I use ffprobe to find out how many frames are encoded I get 600, so that's 24 secs of video.

BUT, when I run those encoded video sequences through `av_read_frame()` I only get like 40-50% of frames processed before `av_read_frame()` returns error code `-12`. So I'm wild guessing that there are some data packages in middle of the streams which get read by `av_read_frame()` and forces a function to return `-12`.

What my questions are, how should I deal with this problem so I can encode full number of frames (600)? When `av_read_frame()` returns value different from `0` should I `av_free_packet()` and proceed to read next frame? Since `av_read_frame()` returns values `< 0` for error codes, which error code is used for `EOF` so I can isolate the end of file code?

Comment: You can also check the flag `eof_reached` in  the struct `AVIOContext` (pointed  by `pb` field of the struct  `AVFormatContext`), when End-of-file happens  , that flag is set then `av_read_frame()` returns 0 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though it's difficult to say what's wrong with your decoding, still `-12` is not a magic number that can't be understood.

```
printf("%s\n", av_err2str(-12));
```

This will print `Cannot allocate memory`, which is the real problem here.

And when getting a positive return value from `av_read_frame()`, it's ok to go on.

`av_free_packet()` has been deprecated, using `av_packet_unref()` instead, at the end of each `av_read_frame()` loop.

```
while(av_read_frame(fmt_ctx, &pkt) >= 0) {
    // decode packet and other stuff
    av_packet_unref(&pkt); 
}
```

At last, usually there's no need to worry about EOF, since `av_decode_video2()` or other decode functions will set a int parameter to proper value indicating whether there is frame to be decompressed.

If you're using a rather new ffmpeg(>=3.1) decoding/encoding API or really need to deal with EOF, compare the return value with `AVERROR_EOF`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using older build of ffmpeg and i have to use `av_free_packet`.

Comment: Anyways, yeah it works now. Thank you for your answer. I shoud've been more careful while reading through functions.

Comment: The error numbers returned by libav are negated standard Unix errors. The -12 comes from: `#define ENOMEM 12`.

Answer (score 0):

for some versions of **libav** the utility `av_err2str` is not compiled, i use the following trick:

```
#undef  av_err2str
#define av_err2str(errnum) av_make_error_string((char*)__builtin_alloca(AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE), AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum)
```