# ffmpeg can not use Android LTE?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg version 3.3.6 to develop an app that displays images of IP cameras on Android.

The code to process receiving the video is completed. The development environment to date is in the same wifi environment as the camera.

However, if you attempt to connect to the camera with the same code in the LTE environment, the `av_read_frame` will terminate with an immediate exit requested error message.

What is the reason for LTE error?

Comment: You are not providing the exact error you are getting. Not sure if this SO post is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713338/ffmpeg-av-read-frame-not-reading-frames-properly

Comment: I guess this camera  configuration only allows local WiFi connection. If your code does not check communication errors early enough, av_read_frame can crash.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Alex Cohn Thanks for the answer. It is a little different from the result you found, but I found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on the same thing and my app works both fine in same WiFI and LTE network. It will be helpful if you can provide the error you are getting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Before looking at the answer, I rewrote all of my source code and compared it to code written in an existing Window environment, and found that I omitted the avformat_stream_info () function. It is working normally. Thank you.